# python unhexlify not working as expected

Tags: python, hex, converters, binary-data, hex-editors

Whenever a program opens a file it sees the file as binary data. It translates it to a higher interpretive language i.e. octal, hex, ascii , etc. In this case it displays hexadecimal in the LH pane and ansi (windows 7 so it should be CP1252) in the RH pane. The 3 pictures below illustrate the original view, then the desired alteration, and the 3rd is the actual change made by the code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
with open(tar,'rb') as f:
data = binascii.hexlify(f.read(160))
if old in data:
    print 'found!'
    data = data.replace(old, new)
else:
    print 'not found'
with open(tar+'new', 'wb') as fo:
    binascii.unhexlify(data)
    fo.write(data)
```

I have obviously not correctly targeted the write delivery method.

Comment: `binascii.unhexlify(data)` is missing assignment。 you appear to be writing out the *hexlified* data only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What is the difference between these two lines:

```
data = binascii.hexlify(f.read(160))

binascii.unhexlify(data)
```

In Python, string objects are immutable. There is nothing you can call upon `data` that will cause the string that `data` names to change, because strings do not change. `binascii.unhexlify` instead returns a **new** string - which is why the first statement even works in the first place. If you wanted to `.write` the resulting new string, then that's what you should specify to happen in the code - either directly:

```
fo.write(binascii.unhexlify(data))
```

or by assigning it back to `data` first.

Comment: I went with the fo.write(binascii.unhexlify(data)) option. Thanks a million.