# python cant get valid conversion from hex to binary

Tags: python, binary, hex, ascii

I have a program that must be able to search a binary file as either hex or ascii. I have the ascii search/replace function working fine, but the previously working hex search/ replace is no longer working. Below is an example of what is happening: The LH is after the change and hex was transposed into the "ascii layer" the RH is the original.
[image]

Included code:

```
    if a_chars>a_digits:alphex = 'a'
else: alphex = 'h'
print alphex
# 3b. if alpha
if alphex == 'a' :
     data = open(tar,'rb').read(160); print('Opening tar file')
     if len(old)>len(new):
          old.ljust(len(old));pad = len(old)- len(new);new = new+(pad*' ')
     if len(old)<len(new):
         print 'NEW: data cannot exceed length of OLD:'
# 3c. if hex
if alphex == 'h' :
     with open(tar,'rb') as f:
          data = binascii.hexlify (f.read(100));print('Opening tar bfile')
     if len(old)>len(new): print 'OLD>NEW hex size must be ='
     if len(old)<len(new): print 'OLD<NEW hex size must be ='    
     old = old.lower();old = ''.join(old.split());print 'old: ', old 
     new = new.lower();new = ''.join(new.split());print 'new: ', new
##sub write new file
fo= open(tarname+time+'.'+tarext,'wb');print 'Creating new file...'
fo.write (data.replace(old,new));print 'Writing file...'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21524348/2926728) given to me on the 3rd of Feb. chasing the trees around I got lost in the forest.

```
data = data.replace(old,new);data = binascii.unhexlify(data)
 fo.write(data);print 'Writing bfile...'
```

I forgot to reassign data back to data (data = binascii.unhexlify(data)) to obtain the corrected output.